# Passing empty strings using double quotes via PowerShell.exe -command

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Seems like a bug... Only thing I can think of is double quotes are being lost through external invocation but it works when the string has a character, so I don't think so. Zero length string fails.

My version:

```
>$host
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 3.0
```

Empty string fails:

```
> powershell.exe -command '&{write-host ""}'
    The string is missing the terminator: ".
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Works if the string has a character:

```
> powershell.exe -command '&{write-host "a"}'
a
```

Works by itself:

```
> &{write-host ""}
<blank line>
```

Works with reversed quotes:

```
>powershell.exe -command "&{write-host ''}"
<blank line>
```

And as @Ansgar pointed out escaping works (\ isn't documented in powershell.exe /?)

```
> powershell.exe -command '&{write-host \"\"}'
<blank line>
```

Comment: I can't really explain it, but the behavior seems to be caused by multiple evaluations due to the combination of `powershell -command`, call operator, and scriptblock. You need 6 double quotes in a row to get the desired behavior, or 4 double quotes in a row if you use just the call operator without the scriptblock (`'& Write-Host """"'`). Escaping the double quotes with backslashes (`'&{Write-Host \"\"}'`) seems to work as well (with or without scriptblock).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yea, seems like a bug in the `-command` text parser. I didn't see any documentation for \ yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be using the at-string parser. The command ends up being:

```
@"'&{write-host ""}'"
```

which reduces to

```
'&{write-host "}'
```

The alternatives are:

```
# Like you said, escape the string
powershell.exe -command '&{write-host \"\"}'

# Use a script block instead of a string
powershell.exe -command {write-host ""}
```

You might also look into using a Base64 encoded command, but I've never gotten that to work.